# Local variable not visible inside OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application and I have a problem:

I have this method:

```
// User has introduced an incorrect password.
private void invalidPassword()
{
    // R.id.string value for alert dialog title.
    int dialogTitle = 0;
    // R.id.string value for alert dialog message.
    int dialogMessage = 0;
    boolean hasReachedMaxAttempts;

    clearWidgets();
    numIntents++;
    hasReachedMaxAttempts = (numIntents > maxNumIntents);

    // Max attempts reached
    if (hasReachedMaxAttempts)
    {
        dialogTitle = R.string.dialog_title_error;
        dialogMessage = R.string.dialog_message_max_attempts_reached;
    }
    else
    {
        dialogTitle = R.string.dialog_title_error;
        dialogMessage = R.string.dialog_message_incorrect_password;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(dialogMessage)
           .setTitle(dialogTitle);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
           {
               // TODO: User clicked OK button
               if (hasReachedMaxAttempts)
               {
               }
               else
               {
               }
           }
       });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

**How can I make visible `boolean hasReachedMaxAttempts;` inside `onClick`?**

Comment: declare it as global variable...

Comment: -2 because I'm new on Java programming. This is how it rewards people who want to learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need that variable to be final;

```
final boolean hasReachedMaxAttemptsFinal = hasReachedMaxAttempts;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 if (hasReachedMaxAttemptsFinal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `final boolean hasReachedMaxAttempts;` variable at `class level` and it should get the task done

Answer (score 2):

It is visible, but it needs to be set to `final`.

```
final boolean hasReachedMaxAttempts = (numIntents > maxNumIntents);
```